# How do you access second parameter of a servlet's web.xml file?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, friendly-url

Say in my web.xml file, I define a servlet like so:

```
<url-pattern>/MyURL/*</url-pattern>
```

How do i access anything passed in the * in my servlet? I'm planning to use use this scheme for pretty(-ish) URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) is exactly for this purpose.

```
String path = request.getPathInfo();
```

That's all. No need to substring the servlet path from it as suggested in another answer here. Also see my answer on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548148/how-to-insert-jsp-functionality-in-servlets).

Answer (score 1):

In the HttpServlet's doGet or doPost method you can use the [getRequestURI](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) method of the [HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object to retrieve the path part of the URL. Since it sounds like you also want to chop off the part of the path that mapped to the serlvet could use the [getServletPath](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) method and then do something like this:

```
String path = request.getRequestURI();
if(path.startsWith(request.getServletPath())) {
    path = path.substring(request.getServletPath().length());
}
```